# Send Mail Function is not working in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, email

I have a send mail function in CommonHelper like

```
   public static function send_plain_email($data){
   $contact_email = CommonHelper::$admin_info['contact_email'];
   $data['subject']= 'contact us';

  Mail::send('emails.'.'plain_email', $data, function($message) use ($data , $contact_email) {
    $message->from($data['email']);
    $message->subject($data['subject']);
    $message->to($contact_email);
    if(!empty($attachment)){
      $message->attach($attachment);
    }
  });
}
```

The data array is coming in this function but Mail::send function giving the following error

```
 {
 "success": false,
 "message": "Undefined variable: data"
 }
```

Which part of the code i am missing here ? any ideas ?

Comment: Have you checked `$data` is null or not ?

Comment: $data is not null , i have checked it .

Comment: Can you please post the `var_dump($data)` output ?

Comment: array:4 [
    "name" => "Tahir"
    "email" => "t@t.com"
     "message" => "This is restlet message."
    "subject" => "contact us"
 ]

Comment: how are you putting the data in your blade?

Comment: Please show your blade file.

Comment: <?php print_r($data) ;?>

Comment: Im still not displaying anything in the blade. It is a blank html page for now with a default message. The $data array is like this:

Comment: $data = [
                'title'=>'Invitation',
                'content'=>'You are invited to try Housing Around App',
                'is_active'=> $request->input('is_active'),
                'house_id' => $request->input('house_id'),
                'role_id'=>$request->input('role_id'),
                'email'=>$request->input('email')
                ];

Comment: Well, if i dont assign any variable from the $data in the blade it redirects me back to the view i expect but still the email has not been sent and i cant assing those to the blade. Any clue what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

check if your blade file have the blade naming extension at the back as follow: file_name.blade.php

Before that i forgot add .blade file extension behind the file name which show as file_name.php it could not detect any variable been sent to the blade.

To display specific data use the following format: {{ $merchant->name }}

Hope this help.